# I can't create new app and version from AppStore for agreement update error showing

Tags: ios, review

From the agreement, text, and banking option can't find anything like the agreement accept the option.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKyUp.png]

Comment: There is also an agreement to accept on account/membership page

Comment: There have no agreements are padding in the account/membership page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the agreement will be contained in its own window with a Accept button on the lower right of the screen. Sometimes App Store Connect doesn't play well in Safari for some reason. I would suggest attempting to load this page in Chrome or another browser.